# How to add own index to pip running in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

- I have a virtualenv with pip inside.
- I have my own package index.
- I want to add this package to pip to avoid invoking `pip install some_package -i my_index` all the time
- I want to add this index only to this specific pip instance running in virtualenv.

In that case, which file should I modify and how?

Answer (score 13):

I run into the same problem, and found that pip support this in current version de facto
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file

Inside a virtualenv:

On Unix and Mac OS X the file is `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`
On Windows the file is: `%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini`

Comment: This solution works on my Mac, but fails to work on RHLE 6. Anyone else get this working in a VE on linux?

Comment: This solution (putting a pip.conf in the root of my virtualenv) worked for me on Centos 7 running python 2.7.5

Comment: @steve Works for me on ubuntu 16.04. Perhaps python / virtualenv version  on RHLE is too old?

Answer (score 10):

I never tried using my own index, but after some research [this article](http://justcramer.com/2011/04/04/setting-up-your-own-pypi-server/) should cover what you want to do.

Basically you need to add the following to your `~/.pip/pip.conf` (on Windows systems, located at `%HOME%\pip\pip.ini`):

```
[global]
index-url = http://my.pypi.index/comes/here
```

The problem is that you will have a global definition for all your projects and what you want is a definition for all your users in the specific project. From [pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#configuration) you can alter the config file lookup by using the environment var `PIP_CONFIG_FILE`

You could edit the `virtual-env-folder/bin/activate` script to include this environment var, but the problem is that creating a new virtual environment would lose this change and would not be possible to automate. What you can do is creating the `.pip/pip.conf` file in the root of your project and creating a simple `activate-virtual-env` script also on the root of the project with the following:

```
pushd $(dirname $0)
export PIP_CONFIG_FILE="$(pwd)/.pip/pip.conf"
source "$(pwd)/virtual-env-folder/bin/activate"
popd
```

and instruct your users to source this file instead of `virtual-env-folder/bin/activate`

Comment: There is no `~` in virtualenv.

Comment: I edited my post with a possible solution to make it project based instead of a global on user based

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are not entirely clear and complete. Add a section (if absent) to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf` (`%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini` on Windows) containing these lines

```
[global]
index-url = https://download.zope.org/ppix
```

where you replace `https://download.zope.org/ppix` with the actual URL of your PyPi index.

Documentation:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/configuration/#naming